# How to find the underlying device for a file on top of ext4 on top of LVM on top of multiple underlying storage devices?

Tags: performance, lvm, ext4, block-device

I have a system with 3 SSD devices (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`) which contain a single LVM logical volume that span over all the devices. I have a single ext4 partition on the logical volume.

I think that one of the SSD devices (`/dev/sdb`) *might* be somewhat faulty and have reduced performance compared to other devices.

Is there a command to get the list of files that are backed by that device?

I know that I can get list of logical segments with `sudo pvdisplay -m` and the output looks like following:

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda
  VG Name               storage
  PV Size               <1,82 TiB / not usable <1,09 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              476932
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          476932
  PV UUID               h3x3O1-1KWj-3pY6-kZ24-MVV4-54UE-ltEdfA
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 476931:
    Logical volume  /dev/storage/vm
    Logical extents 0 to 476931
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb
  VG Name               storage
  PV Size               <3,64 TiB / not usable <3,84 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              953861
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          953861
  PV UUID               MsNlhh-W2It-CbX4-IxJn-lXJN-hlcd-EpBh9Q
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 953860:
    Logical volume  /dev/storage/vm
    Logical extents 476932 to 1430792
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc
  VG Name               storage
  PV Size               <3,64 TiB / not usable <3,84 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              953861
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          953861
  PV UUID               sklK6w-XZd6-DqIp-ZT1g-O9rj-1ufw-UaC0z4
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 953860:
    Logical volume  /dev/storage/vm
    Logical extents 1430793 to 2384653
```

So I know that logical extends 476932 to 1430792 are the potentially problematic area. How to map this logical segment range to actual files on the filesystem (ext4) on top of the LVM?

Basically I'm trying to figure out if the device is actually faulty or if the usage pattern for these files might be unlucky enough that I'm hitting usage pattern that's problematic for the hardware and the performance is worse than expected. No device is showing any errors and all the data looks good, but the performance of this single device appears to be worse than expected.

The system is in use so I'd prefer to diagnose this online without overwriting any data. I know that if I could simply take the potentially problematic storage device offline and overwrite its contents, I could use `fio` to benchmark it to see if it's working below spec or not.

```
$ lsblk -s
...
storage-vm 253:0    0   9,1T  0 lvm  /mnt/storage
├─sda        8:0    0   1,8T  0 disk 
├─sdb        8:16   0   3,7T  0 disk 
└─sdc        8:32   0   3,7T  0 disk
```

I'm basically asking how to get list of files backed by a single storage device when the filesystem spans over multiple storage devices.

Or if you can provide instructions how to figure where a given *file* is actually stored, that would be fine, too. I would then run that routine for every file to figure out which files are backed by the device I'm interested in. I'm aware that it could be that a single big file is backed by all devices if the file is fragmented over a big range of locigal segments so the answer could be that a single file is backed by all the devices but I have currently no idea how to do this either.

```
$ sudo vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               storage
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        3
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                3
  Act PV                3
  VG Size               <9,10 TiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              2384654
  Alloc PE / Size       2384654 / <9,10 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               MOrTMY-5Dly-48uQ-9Fa8-JNvf-tont-9in7ol

$ sudo lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/storage/vm
  LV Name                vm
  VG Name                storage
  LV UUID                RDkaLH-mh6C-cXxT-6ojc-DxkB-o4jD-3CMHdl
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time staging, 2021-01-21 09:57:06 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <9,10 TiB
  Current LE             2384654
  Segments               3
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```